# How do I prove this is a covering map?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p : \Bbb{R} \to S^1$ be given by $x \mapsto (\cos(2 \pi x), \sin (2 \pi x))$ and let $i : \Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}^+$ be the identity map.

Then $p \times i$ is a covering map. Now suppose $f : S^1 \times \Bbb{R}^+ \to \Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ is the homeomorphism given by $(x, t) \mapsto tx.$

How do you show $f \circ(p \times i)$ is a covering map? I'm stuck at finding the inverse image of an open set in $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$ and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix a $t$, then the image of $f$ is a circle of radius $t$ in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. From this you may see that $t$ is the *height* of your circle if you consider $S^1\times \mathbb{R}_+$ as an infinite cylinder of radius 1. Hence an annulus of inner radius $t$ and outer radius $T$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be a *finite* cylinder in $S^1\times \mathbb{R}_+$, starting at *height* $t$ and ending at *height* $T$. The rest is then to figure out inverse images under $p\times i$, which I infer is apparent to you.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask if you will please consider finding $f^{-1}(U)$ where $U$, say, is $(-2, -1) \times (1, 2)$? I'm terrible at visualizing all that is going on and would like to see how you would work this out.

Comment: The distances of the points closest of the origin, and farthest from origin of $U$ are $t = \sqrt{2}$ and $T = \sqrt{8}$. Your set $U$ will lie in the annulus with inner radius $t$ and outer radius $T$. So inverse image of $U$ will lie inside a cylinder which _starts_ at height $t$ and _ends_ at height $T$.